# Construction of a spin chain Hamiltonian invariant under a finite subgroup of SO(3)

Tags: condensed-matter, group-representations, topological-order, spin-chains

I would like to construct a 2-local Hamiltonian that acts on a 1D spin chain where each spin transforms as the 3D irrep of $A_4$ which is a subgroup of $SO(3)$. I know that an $SO(3)$ invariant Hamiltonian can be constructed using the Casimir operator like $H = \sum_i \vec{S_i} . \vec{S_{i+1}}$. Is there a similar thing for finite groups (i.e equivalent of a Casimir)? I would explicitly like the on site symmetry to be only $A_4$ and nothing bigger. (eg: I cannot just use  $H = \sum_i \vec{S_i} . \vec{S_{i+1}}$). I also need parity and translation invariance but I know how to impose those.

Comment: You might be interested that there's an offhand remark in [this](http://mathoverflow.net/a/74701) MO answer about a Casimir analogue for finite groups, even stating its form as $1 - \frac{1}{\lvert G \rvert} \sum_{g \in G} \delta_g$.

Comment: Note that a possible value for the generators of $A_4$ in the $3D$ irrep are $S = \begin {pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&-1&0 \\0&0&-1 \end {pmatrix}$ and $T = \begin {pmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&0&1 \\1&0&0 \end {pmatrix}$, with $S^2=T^3=(ST)^3=1$. So you have to find an hamiltonian invariant by $S$ and $T$.

Comment: Assuming $(S_i)_x= \begin {pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&-i \\0&i&0 \end {pmatrix},  (S_i)_y \begin {pmatrix} 0&0&i\\0&1&0 \\-i&0&0 \end {pmatrix}, (S_i)_z= \begin {pmatrix} 0&-i&0\\i&0&0 \\0&0&1 \end {pmatrix}$, the "hamiltonian" $H = \sum\limits_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^3 ((S_i)_j)^2 \otimes ((S_{i+1})_j)^2$, is invariant by $A_4$, but is not invariant by $SO(3)$

Comment: @Trimok thanks. However, are you sure there are no larger finite groups that also leave the Hamiltonian you suggested invariant?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I looked at the MO answer. I could not figure out what $\delta$ means. Although it looks promising. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I believe it is simply a Dirac/Kronecker delta $\delta_g h = 1 \text{ iff } h = g \text{ else } \delta_g h = 0$, but I could be wrong.

Comment: In the MO answer, he's defining an element of the group algebra.  The element $\delta_g$ is just the basis element of the group algebra corresponding to the element $g$.

Comment: @abyssawd : No, I am not sure.